Not having write permissions for a file in a docker container
Every time I want to edit and save a file using a text editor like Sublime Text or VS Code, it requires my password. The files are part of a Django project in a docker container. Only the root user has write permissions. How can I set this so it doesn't require password? Also there's a lock icon on the project folders that have this problem.

I tried adding my user to docker group to solve this problem but it didn't resolve.

What is the actual error?  Where is the file you're trying to edit?  I wouldn't necessarily try to edit files directly in a container; can you use a non-Docker Python virtual environment for day-to-day development?

There's no error, it is just annoying to enter password for every edits and saves I do to a file (only the files in the folders with lock icon require password). How can I do it in any other way that doesn't require any passwords? It's the prompt Sublime Text shows when requesting the password: authentication needed to run 'bin/cp/' as super user. I'm using Ubuntu 22. (I'm a beginner and don't know how not to edit a file directly in a container.)

Are you referring to your docker password?

No. My Ubuntu user's login password.
